# How to efficiently split a string, add it to a List, and convert to a Double?

Tags: c#, split

I have some basic code that does what I want it to do, but I think it can be abbreviated / cleaned up. I am struggling a bit on how to do so, however.

The code reads as follows:

```
List<string> positions = new List<string>();
List<string> players = new List<string>();

foreach (string element in fractionedList)
{
   positions.Add(element.Split(',')[2]); 
   positions.Add(element.Split(',')[3]); 
   positions.Add(element.Split(',')[4]); 

   players.Add(element.Split(',')[5]); 
   players.Add(element.Split(',')[6]); 
   players.Add(element.Split(',')[7]);
} 

List<double> convertedPositions = positions.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
List<double> convertedPlayers = playerss.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

For reference, my fractionedList will look something like:

```
"string0,string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6,string7,string8,string9,string10,string11,string12",
"string0,string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6,string7,string8,string9,string10,string11,string12",
"string0,string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6,string7,string8,string9,string10,string11,string12",
"string0,string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6,string7,string8,string9,string10,string11,string12",
```

So I am trying to split each string instance of the List, get the next three elements, and then add them to a new List and then convert that List to a new List of doubles. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to handle the Split method. Is there an equivalent to Take()? Also, can this all be done in one List creation, rather than creating a List of strings, creating a List of doubles?

Comment: Each string seems to have 13 elements, can you please explain more about which parts (indices) you want to extract and why? How about a couple of real examples? And please post a [mcve], right now the example cannot be parsed to doubles, and the code didn't compile because you were missing some parenthesis so I'm not entirely sure the code *accurately* represents what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would perform the conversion inline, without the need to store in an initial string list

```
List<double> convertedPositions = new List<double>();
List<double> convertedPlayers = new List<double>();

foreach (string element in fractionedList)
{
    var elements = element.Split(',');

    convertedPositions.AddRange(elements.Skip(2).Take(3).Select(x=> Convert.ToDouble(x)));
    convertedPositions.AddRange(elements.Skip(5).Take(3).Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x));
}
```

Comment: @maccettura beat me by a few minutes and provides nearly the same answer -- I didn't see his answer until after I posted mine.  He should be awarded the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I would change is to not split your string 6 times for no reason.  Split it once and store the result in a variable.

With a little LINQ you could shorten your code:

```
List<double> positions = new List<double>();
List<double> players = new List<double>();

foreach (string element in fractionedList)
{
    string[] elementSplit = element.Split(',');
    positions.AddRange(elementSplit.Skip(2).Take(3).Select(x => double.Parse(x));
    players.AddRange(elementSplit.Skip(5).Take(3).Select(x => double.Parse(x)); 
}
```

What my code does is split your `element` variable on `,` like you were doing (now only doing it once).  Then using Linq's `Take()` and `Skip()` I am selecting the `[2,3,4]` and `[5,6,7]` indices and adding them to their respective lists (after parsing to double).

Keep in mind that this code will throw an exception if your string input is something that can not reasonably parse into a double.  If you are certain that the input will always be good then this code should get you there the quickest.